# What are the advantages/disadvantages of a pull `while` loop compared push `while` loop in Bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, process-substitution

There are many ways one can consume data in a while loop in bash.

One such is

```
some_proc | while read line
            do
            something
            done
```

Another is

```
 while read line
            do
            something
            done < <(some_proc)
```

Question 1: When should I prefer one over the other.

Question 2: If I am not reading from a process `some_proc` but using `redirection` directly on a file, when is that file opened and closed.

Comment: In the first the loop is run in a subshell and so all rules applied to subshells apply, for example variables are lost when the subshell exits. The second is better in practically all situations.

Comment: @User112638726 Thanks !

Comment: @User112638726 Except if one wants to be compatible with `sh`. Then only the first option is available.

Comment: @user000001 The title says in bash, but ok.